# A "turn" (gymnastics/dance) in French?

Tags: usage, terminologie, sport

I would like to know what is the common word of "turn" in French. Turn as in the sense of gymnastic or dance.

I want to say *tourne* but the dictionaries couldn't really confirm if that is the correct translation.

Alternatives are *virage* and *rotation* but both feels slightly weird.

Comment: Voir peut-êrte un **axel** en patinage artistique ..

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington je ne suis pas un expert mais je pense que de nombreuses figures de patinage et pas seulement l’axel impliquent un ou plusieurs tours sur soi-même.

Comment: Please provide further context, a sequence/sentence involving this, a diagram, links to dictionary entries. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should better explain what kind of "turn" your are thinking of, but here are some suggestions about various ways to do turns:

- *un tour* (e.g.: *faire un tour sur soi-même*)
- *une pirouette*
- *une cabriole*
- *une rotation*
- *un pivot*
- *un soleil*
- *un saut périlleux*
- *un salto*
- *une galipette* ;-)

Comment: i am looking specifically for a translation in the context of dancing or gymnastics:

Comment: Yes, you already wrote that in your question but there are many different ways to do a turn in both of these activities. If you look for a generic term that encompasses most of them, just use *faire un tour/une rotation* )

Comment: If you describe more what the dancer/gymnast does when performing a turn, we could give a more precise translation.

Answer (score 1):

another word could be **vrille**, this is when you turn around the vertical axis

Answer (score 1):

another word could be "une volte"